# Can you give a very simple example of Java ThreadManager running in Google Apple Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Tried to run this code in App Engine but got Permission error

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your code here
                    list.remove("coo");
                }
            }, 
            3000 
    );
```

The above code run periodically every 3 seconds.

I want to do the same in Google App Engine, but do not know how. I heard that we can use  `ThreadManager`  or `Runnable` or something likes that.

So, can you give a very simple example of how to run a `Thread` inside Google Apple Engine?

Comment: You would use cron for repeated tasks, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron. Threads are coupled to the parent request, so they are limited in their execution time.

Comment: @konqi, what if I want it to run every 5 secs? Can cron help?

Comment: I think the minimum is 1 minute for cron. Since cron is a backend task you'd have a 10 minute deadline. So you could sleep a bit during those 10 minutes. Possibly create a volatile lock with memcache so only a single instance of your task will run. I would try to avoid such tasks entirely though.

Comment: you could start a long Task Queue job. that will run your threads (do anything every n seconds) for say 10 minutes, and call itself again (through Task Queue), and so on

Comment: anyway, it depends on what you actually want. I don't think "run thread every 3 second" is your final goal. what you actually want to reach by this?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, i want to build chat app but do not want to store chat message in datastore in in a **public static varible** & thus I want to put data into that variable & other function will check that variable every 3 secs to get data

Comment: do you understand that Appengine instances are ephemeral? can be killed at any unpredicted moment, that happend very often, w/o any prior notification, all memory data will be lost. also there're many of them running in parallel, on different machines, so each instance will have own state of such variable. and client cannot choose which instance to connect to

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, you you suggest that I should not store chat message into "public static varible"?

Comment: yes, I mean you _must_ use database to store your state. appengine app must be stateless by itself

Comment: But I put data into a HashMap variable then 3 secs later I get the data & then clear up the variable? Why Google clean up the memory suddenly like that? Also, you mean mywebapp is running in many webservers?

Comment: Maybe it will be there, or maybe your app will be killed before and you'll lose your data. And yes, many webservers, each have own variable, not shared between servers

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, Google is a big company, I don't think they provide such bad service? What if Google clears memory at the time we create users "**User u=new User();**", will my app will die? Why Google said the the Up-time is 99.99%?

Comment: why bad? it's not a bug, it's a feature, it's why people choose appengine. it's how fault tolerant app are designed usually, it's how it works, how scaling works. it's called _Cloud_. Also I didn't say app will die. I said it have temp time frame for execution, nodes up/down when you have more/less requests, not working all the time